# hover appearing and disappearing

Tags: html, css

Right now I have an image that has another image absolutely positioned on top of the first one. Both images are inside an a tag.

I am trying to get it so that when I hover on any part of the first image, both the first image goes from .5 opacity to full, and the 2nd image goes from 0 opacity to full.

I've been able to make the hover work for the image but the 2nd image only activates it's opacity when I hover directly on it, rather than highlighting both when I'm on either of them.

```
<div class="of-volume image-column">
                    <a href="http://www.greatlengthshair.co.uk/hair-extensions/">
                        <img src="img/artistry-1-bg.jpg" alt="artisans of volume link" class="image-link">
                        <img src="img/artistry-1-icon.png" alt="" class="artisan-icon">
                    </a>
                </div>

/*//////////////////////////////////////
    IMAGE NAV
//////////////////////////////////////*/

.image-column {
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    width: 33.3333%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}

.image-column a {
    opacity: .5;
}

.image-column a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.artisan-icon {
    position: absolute;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 25px;
}
```

Comment: We need code, please!

Comment: If you post no code, you will obtain no help.

Comment: Your code does not fit to your question. You set `opacity` to `<a>` which effects both images equally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put both absolute images inside a relative div, then did set the `:hover` selector on this container.

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#container {
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
}

img {
  position:absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left:0px;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s; /* Safari */
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

#pic1 {
  opacity:0.0;

}

#pic2 {
  opacity:0.5;
}

#container:hover #pic1, #container:hover #pic2  {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id=container>
<img id=pic1 class=picture src="http://i.imgur.com/tMVGqP6.jpg" alt=img>
<img id=pic2 class=picture src="http://i.imgur.com/Goy7oBy.gif" alt=img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed up most of your CSS rules. Just attach the desired effects to the correct hover state:

```
.image-link { opacity: 0.5; }
.artisan-icon { opacity: 0; }
a:hover .image-link { opacity: 1; }
a:hover .artistan-icon { opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: But see I already tried this method, but it makes it so the smaller second image highlights when hovered on, and the first image when it's hovered on, but I am trying to make it so that if you hover on either of them, both of their opacities activate.